# Execute script at random times per day

Tags: python-3.x

I have a script which perform several things when executed, it accepts `--start_date=SOMEDATE`, `--end_date=SOMEDATE`, and `--actions=200`.

For example:

```sh
python3 myscript --start_date=2019-02-12 --end_date=2020-02-01 --actions=100
```

Which means it has to make 100 `actions` between the `start_date` and `end_date`. Is there a way to calculate the times?

Here is the logic I'm considering:

There are **31 days** between the start and end dates, so maybe `actions // (end_date - start_date)` gives me the number of *actions per day*, but how can I make those *actions per day* completely random within the day?

Comment: Tried to cleanup the language and formatting to make the question more understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is get the unix timestamps. Do

```
upper_bound = timestamp_end - timestamp_start
```

Where the `timestamp_start` and `timestamp_end` are the start and end dates.
Then generate `N` random numbers between `0` and `upperbound`.
Afterwards just execute the script at `timestamp_start + random_number`